# Single quote formatting issue in curl syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I integrated linkedin with Rails 4 and trying to share post on linkedin.

I used curl in `rails and post on linked-in wall` using below curl post. I used below code in rails console and its work fine but when i used it in rails code with system and `single quote` then issue create because already single quote use in inside.

```
system 'curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"comment":"hello from system www.google.com! http://google.com","visibility":{"code":"anyone"}}'  https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token=xxxxxXygzp_8E3xxvg7_7FaxxxxxxnxtWzBXAxxxxa0wta5z1MVK6-kubHJ5JxxxndpAMc_CxmCsIHxFlxxx0t_WNEhxxxMz8_cKpeOidAxxx5-X-MdvzYVxxQ&format=json&title=linkedin HTTP/1.1'
```

What do I have to add to resolve this issue? I tried a lot then I posted here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you should use an HTTP library (I use HTTParty, but there are many other options) inside your rails app, not curl. I think that may make your life easier.

Comment: Can you give me that code.

Comment: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

Comment: Thanks buddy, I used httparty and its work.

Comment: Great! I posted as an answer so you can upvote/accept as you see fit. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application (as opposed to in the terminal), I suggest you use an HTTP library (I use [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty), but there are many options).

Comment: Thanks buddy. Good